# How to fix "fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory" in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks

I'm writing a script which deletes old backup files. I've included `filesystem` as I would normally do, but this time, I got this error:

```
fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
```

I tried to include `experimental/filesystem` and I set `-lstdc++fs` as GCC flag. Nothing has worked for me.

**Example code:**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    fs::path const directory{ "C:\Test" };
    std::vector<fs::directory_entry>::size_type const num_files_to_keep{ 5 };
    ...
```

Comment: The `std::filesystem` namespace was introduced in C++17. Does your version of GCC (I assume, considering your talk about `-lstdc++fs`) support C++17? Do you need to add the `-std=c++17` flag explicitly?

Comment: I'm on GCC version 8.2.0. So there shouldn't be a problem. I've added "-std=c++17". Still failing to build.

Comment: OT: `fs::path const directory{ "C:\Test" };` You need to escape your \ or use /

Answer (score 1):

Using CodeBlocks ang GCC 8.0 or above You need to set c++17 compiler option
(I'm using CodeBlock last Nightly build).
[image: Project build options]
Then you must add to the Linker settings options the `stdc++fs` library.[image: Linker settings]

And then you must add the `#include <filesystem>` directive, from GCC 8.0, and not `<experimental/filesystem>` 
On windows the directory separator is `\\` (two backslash). 
You need to write:

```
fs::path const directory { "C:\\Test" };
```