# I've got "fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory" in Code::Blocks [using GCC 8.2.0]

Tags: mingw, c++17, codeblocks

I'm trying to run the code in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37494654/6784796), but I've got the following error:

> fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987678/how-to-fix-fatal-error-filesystem-no-such-file-or-directory-in-codeblocks) is a **similar question**, and I applied all the steps in the answer, but it doesn't work.

More details about my environment:

My operating system is Windows 10.

I installed codeblocks-17.12mingw-setup.exe from this [link](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26).

I set the option:

```
Have g++ follow the coming C++1z (aka C++17) ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++1z]
```

The result of executing the command "g++ --version" is: "g++ (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-3) 8.2.0"

Comment: Try adding all the options explicitly on the command line: `g++ -std=c++1z <filename>.cpp -lstdc++fs` and see if that works. If it does,  then something in your setup is not done correctly; if it does not, then maybe your g++ does not support these things. FWIW, I tried with g++ 8.3.1 on Fedora and it works fine.

Comment: @NickD, It doesn't work. I've got many lines of errors.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the errors: it's the only way that somebody from the outside might be able to figure out what's happening. But maybe 8.2.0 does not support this?